# Cortana Bot works only with launch name or utterance

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding, cortana

I've published a Cortana bot and it works only for the first time if I launch it with its invocation name or utterance.

After that whatever I speak it always writes this message - " I can't connect at the moment. Please try again in a little bit"

After debugging remotely I did see the Bot receives the text in Activity and progresses without any error.

The same bot is working fine in Skype and WebChannel but it does not work in Cortana post first utterance.

I've also tried searching SO and ended up opening up a Issue at Bot-Builder [repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3206).

My Bot ID: 5225e5ae-c580-4f8d-88d5-e8c8001a5242

Comment: Based on the multiple Internal Server Error and Gateway Timeout errors in your Cortana channel, it looks like there is a problem with your bot code.

Comment: I have not received any Internal Server Error, not even once

Comment: Check the errors/warnings for the Cortana channel in the bot portal, you can see them there.